# Java Properties: loading null from a .txt file

Tags: java, text, properties

so I'm currently working on reading information from a text file from the first time, and from what I have pieced together, the following code should work and return 100 and 16:

```
package Utility;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class textReader {
public textReader()
{}

public Object fetchElement(String fileName, String keyName)
{

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("P:/Real_Time_Survival/Real_Time_Survivial_Game/assets" + fileName));
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }


  return properties.getProperty("keyName");
}
}
```

but when called from the main class with

```
 textReader ready = new textReader();
 ready.fetchElement("Sprites/ExampleSprite/Default/SpriteData.txt", "FrameDuration");
 ready.fetchElement("Sprites/ExampleSprite/Default/SpriteData.txt", "AnimationFrames");
```

It returns null (have the system printing out those lines, cut it out due to formatting errors). Any idea as to why this won't work?

Comment: print the stack trace of the ioexception. chances are high there is already an exception when reading the file....

Comment: I was missing "/" after assets, silly me, but after adding a line to print out if there is an exception, I can see that there is not one.  The file I am trying to read is as follows: FrameDuration:100
AnimationFrames:16             Is this improperly formatted?

Comment: I've used an example of properly formatted information in the file, yet that too returns null. I'm kinda stumped here, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to stick my neck out and guess you left off a "/" after "assets"

Answer (score 0):

I um, put the keyName variable as a string.

Yep this is solved, 10/10 best dumb mistakes ever